# add and retriving image from access database in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

How can I add and retrieve images from Microsoft Access database and also retrieve them using C# WinForms?

Comment: What kind of fields are they stored in? Generic BLOBs or OLE?

Answer (score 0):

Look at using the .net oledb data provider for saving and retrieving blob(binary large object) values in a database.

http://cs.pervasive.com/forums/t/717.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Convert image into byte[] and insert into column of type image.
While retrieve check is not null and then read from datareader and typecast into byte[].

```
 if (dr["Image"] != DBNull.Value && dr["Image"] != null)
                            {
                                Image = (byte[])dr["Image"];
                            }
```

From byte[] you can convert into image

```
Image img;
Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(m_Image));
```